# Validity of ∃x(Qx→∀x Qx ).

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I was reading through Enderton's "Mathematical Introduction to Logic" and came across 2 examples, one a formula, one a relationship:

1. ∃x(Qx→∀x Qx)
2. ∀y∃x Pxy $\nvDash$ ∃x∀yPxy

Enderton claims the first one is a validity. I fail to see how this is the case. How would I show this?

For the second one, I explicitly defined a predicate P: a 2 place predicate that says ($y*x = 1)$ so the statement would read as following: For all y, there exists such that ($y*x = 1)$ but the right side would read: there exists x such that for all y, ($y*x = 1)$. Now if you do it the converse way, ie ∃x∀yPxy  $\vDash$ ∀y∃x Pxy then this relationship is actually true. My question is, is the example I provided enough to show the relationship holds for (2)?

edit: Not an exact duplicate, since there is a second part of the question that is not answered in the linked thread.

Comment: ∃x(Q(x)→∀x Q(x)) is ∃x(~Q(x) or ∀x Qx). If the right hand side of the second expression is false, then ∃x(~Q(x)) is true.

Comment: With regard to your second question, are you insinuating that showing that the converse is true implies that the initial statement is false? Because that is not the case. (ex: P iff Q)

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I am asking if the example I've defined is enough to show ∀y∃x Pxy ⊭ ∃x∀yPxy. Can I explicitly define Pxy or does it have to be arbitrary?

Comment: For the first part of the question, see the post: [why-is-this-true $\exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall y Py)$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py)

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of (1) is that we can let $y$ be the "least $Q$ish" of all elements. If $y$ is actually $Q$ish, then all elements must be $Q$ish!

For instance if the least tall person, $y$, is actually tall, then all persons $x$ are tall. So
$$Qy\to \forall xQ(x)$$
and hence
$$\exists y(Qy\to \forall xQ(x)).$$

Answer (score 1):

The second part is trivial.

In order to show that:

> $∀y∃x Pxy \nvDash ∃x∀yPxy$,

consider the domain $\mathbb N$ and interpret $P$ with $\ge$ (i.e. $P^{\mathbb N} = \ge$).

Clearly: $∀m∃n \ (n \ge m)$ holds but $∃n∀m (n \ge m)$ does not (i.e. $\mathbb N \vDash ∀m∃n \ (n \ge m)$ and $\mathbb N \nvDash ∃n∀m (n \ge m)$).