# A curious logical formula involving prime numbers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $S$ be a nonempty set of natural numbers. Is the following formula
$$
\exists p\ \bigl(\text{$p$ is prime } \rightarrow \forall x  \text{ ($x$ is prime)}\bigr) 
$$
true or false on $S$? I know the answer to this question, but what would be the shortest way to arrive to the conclusion using some deduction system?

Comment: Hint: $A \to B$ is true if $A$ is false.

Comment: See [Drinker's Paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py) : the formula is an instance of an *universally valid* formula.

Comment: The "shortest way to arrive at the conclusion" will depend on _which_ deduction system you mean when you say "some deduction system". If I can choose one myself, I'l define a deductive system where I've declared the drinker formula to be a _logical axiom_; then the proof is very short!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier - in the linked post there are many proofs of it: it is enough to replace $P(x)$ with "$x \text { is prime }$" in one of them.