# Quantifier difference notation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

(1)$\exists x \in X \ ( P(x)  \implies \forall y \in X P(y) )$

(2) $\exists x\in X P(x) \implies \forall y \in X P(y)$

What’s the difference? And are they both always true?

It seems to me that the second is false, but I read that the first is true. May someone please clarify the difference? And tell me why that is the case, please?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication) : $∀xPx → ∀yPy$, which is always true.

---

The second one is not equivalent to the first one, and is not always true. Consider the following counter-example : "if there is a number that is even, then every number is even".

To have an insight about the difference, consider what happens to the first one with the same interpretation used above : domain $\mathbb N$ and predicate symbol $P(x)$ interpreted with "$x$ is Even".

We have that $\forall y P(y)$ is False (because it is not true that every *natural* is Even).

But also $P(1)$ is False.

Thus, $P(1) \to \forall y P(y)$ is True (because $\text F \to \text F$ is $\text T$) and thus :

> $\exists x (Px \to \forall y P(y))$

is True.

---

See the so-called [Drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

And see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py) for proofs of the validity of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction is in the placement of the brackets, and the operator precedence.

---

> $\exists x\in X~\Big(P(x)\to\forall y\in X~P(y)\Big)$

This states: "There is something in $X$ where *if* that thing satisfies $P$, *then* everything in $X$ satisfies $P$".   Now, implications are *only false* when their antecedent is true and consequent false.   However, when the consequent is false, then *there is something* in $X$ that makes the antecedent false too.

So you can always find something in $X$ that makes the implication hold (well, unless there is no things in $X$).

So, as long as $X$ is *not empty*, this existential statement is true.

---

Because implication has precedance over quantification, there is *implicit* brackettng around the existential in the antecedant.

> $\Big(\exists x\in X~P(x)\Big)\to\forall y\in X~P(y)$

This states "*If* there is something in $X$ that satisfies $P$, *then* everything in $X$ will satisfy $P$."

It is possible to have an $X$ and $P$ that make this implication false.