# Is there a difference between $\exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \forall y\phi(y))$ and $\exists x \phi(x) \rightarrow \forall y\phi(y)$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Is there a difference between $\exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \forall y\phi(y))$ and $\exists x \phi(x) \rightarrow \forall y\phi(y)$?

The first one is the Drinker's paradox, which is a true in an non-empty domain (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py?noredirect=1&lq=1)). But isn't the second one also true in a non-empty domain? I'm suspicious because I've never seen the Drinker's paradox written the second way.

Comment: See [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication): the first one is equiv to $∀xϕ(x)→∀yϕ(y)$

Comment: How to find "the difference"? Finding a model where $∀yϕ(y)$ is False and where  $∃xϕ(x)$ is True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the domain be $\{1,2\}$ and let $\phi(1) = \top$ and $\phi(2) = \bot$. The first statement is true since for $x=2$, we have $\neg\phi(x)$. The second is false since $\exists x \phi(x)$ is true (since $\phi(1) = \top$), but $\forall y \phi(y)$ is false (since $\phi(y) =\bot$).

Answer (score 3):

Take the domain to be the prime numbers and $\phi(x)$ to mean "$x$ is even". Then $\exists x \phi(x)$ is true since $2$ is even, but $\forall y \phi(y)$ is false since $3$ is not even.

The reason the drinker's paradox holds is that you can make sure a suitable $x$ exists: if everyone is drinking, take $x$ to be arbitrary; if not everyone drinks, choose $x$ to be any non-drinker. However, for the second statement you give, when not everyone drinks, taking a non-drinker makes the antecedent true, and that makes the entire sentence false.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence "However...". The formula $\exists x \phi(x) \to \forall y\phi(y)$ is false when someone but not everyone is drinking. Indeed, in this case, and only in this case, the is antecedent true, while the consequent is false. The sentence $\exists x (\phi(x) \to \forall y \phi(y))$, instead, holds in any case.